# Manage Hibernate transactions with Spring @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactional

I face a problem with Spring3 and Hibernate4.
I would like to use @Transactional to manage hibernate transactions. My JUnit test works with HSQDB. But when deployed on Tomcat, an exception occures.

I tried many configurations, and the one which works with unit testing consists in deleting hibernate.current_session_context_class property in session factory configuration. Then in server mode, the exception below occures :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:990)
at myproject.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.create(UserDaoImpl.java:37)
```

When I configure hibernate.current_session_context_class to value "thread", then the exception is :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction
at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:348)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.save(Unknown Source)
at myproject.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.create(UserDaoImpl.java:39)
```

Here is my configuration :

```
<beans>
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyDataSource"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>myproject.dao.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Where are you defining your transactional annotations and how are your unit tests running? Using Spring's test helper classes?

Comment: Search for "openSessionInViewFilter", your unit tests work because they open and close their own sessions. Its likely you have not yet told your web application that it needs to do that; thus your transactions don't have a session to operate w/in. I'd provide more detail, but I have to run for the time being. I'll check back on this question later.

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of HibernateTemplate as it does the transaction management automatically. Configuring transactions is little headache.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a good beginning for an answer but far from complete. Try to make your answer more robust, include steps and detailed description. Then I'll be happy to up-vote a good answer.